# python read a multiple files in order

Tags: python, file-io

I have files in an order something like this:

H2_000.csv,
H2_001.csv,
H2_002.csv,
H2_003.csv,
H2_004.csv,
H2_005.csv.

```
import glob

path = 'path/H2_*.csv'
files=glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    f=open(file, 'r')
    print f

output
open file 'path/H2_003.csv', mode 'r' at 0x7f3ce9eca150,
open file 'path/H2_000.csv', mode 'r' at 0x7f3ce9eca1e0,
open file 'path/H2_004.csv', mode 'r' at 0x7f3ce9eca150,
open file 'path/H2_001.csv', mode 'r' at 0x7f3ce9eca1e0,
```

but this reads the file randomly, 
I want the file to be open in an order. 
Can any one help me. thanks!

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: Please paste your code in your question. Anyway, the solution is surelly `for element in sorted(your_list)`. Now you pasted, I confirme: `for file in sorted(files)` should do the job.

Comment: how are you getting this list..H2_000.csv, H2_001.csv, H2_002.csv, H2_003.csv, H2_004.csv, H2_005.csv ? As you get the list of files just sort it  and use loop to open the files

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is sort the list of files (and also always use `with`)

```
import glob

path = 'path/H2_*.csv'
files=glob.glob(path)
for file in sorted(files):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        print f
```

Comment: don't forget `with` it will close files for you even when an exception occurs